# Getting colour ramps and other funky styles in the ArcGIS REST API's DrawingInfo or elsewhere

Tags: style, api, arcgis-rest-api

I have some layers with "funky" styling, they contain colour ramps, or hashes across the line (mimicking train tracks), or dashes with different spacings. I'm reading all of these layers from an [ArcGIS map server](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/map-service.htm) and using the drawingInfo to generate Mapbox styling objects.

However while I can get the renderer type (simple, Unique value, and Class breaks) and line/circle/fill/etc type, I can't see these funky additions anywhere in the returned drawingInfo objects from the rest API. I can see that color ramp objects [definitely exist](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/common-data-types/color-ramp-objects.htm).

How am I able to programmatically discover these extra styling flourishes on my layers?